# Google Closure Compiler shell script in Mac OS

Tags: google-closure-compiler

On my PC I'm using this bat script to compile my JavaScript project:
https://github.com/ChristianDen/fx.js/blob/master/build/compile.bat

And it works great!

Now, I want to run that on Mac using Terminal.
So far, I've renamed the script with an .sh extensions and made sure Java is installed.

I don't have a lot of Mac experience, but it won't run.
Have you any experience with this?

Comment: Batch files are Windows-only, so you'll have to change `^` to ```\``` and get rid of the last line in order to make it a valid shell script. I'd also look into [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). It runs on both platforms.

Comment: Holy cannoli! It works! Thanks.